# Getting log as The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by Appium

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

Below is the parameter I have set to get Appium session but I got error desired capabilities not recognized by appium for no-reset, app-activity, app-pkg, session-override, pre-launch below is my code snippet.

```
switch (platForm) {
    case "Android":
        capability.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capability.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        capability.setCapability("app-pkg", "com.f24.alert");
        capability.setCapability("app-activity", "com.f24.alert.LoginActivity");
        capability.setCapability("app",dataSutiteBaseData.AppUrl);
        capability.setCapability("session-override", true);
        capability.setCapability("no-reset", false);
        capability.setCapability("pre-launch",true);
        break;
    case "IOS":
```

Answer (score 3):

See here:

http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#appium-server-capabilities

Looks like some of your names may be out of date, e.g. the above indicates that it should be `appPackage`, not `app-pkg`, which is deprecated.

Comment: Currently I am following documentation for latest release, I am trying use Appium 'Server flags' 
http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#server-flags

Comment: What is your appium version?

Comment: Appium Version 1.4.16.1

Comment: The docs for 1.4.16 still seem to state `appPackage`:

appPackage Java package of the Android app you want to run com.example.android.myApp 

http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.4.16/?java#appium-server-capabilities

As the latest release is 1.5, it might be best to check the docs relevant to your version.